# Zend form validation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I am using Zend Form to create dynamic form.

I have Zend Form validation too.

Trying to remove Validation dynamically, but not getting any success.

Can you plz help me to remove Zend Validation.

Bellow is my code for remove validation :

```
$toRemValArray = array();
$toRemValArray[0] = 'ele_4af42ceac7810';

if(isset($_POST['btnPost_x'])){                 
    if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
        $allElements = $form->getElements();
        foreach($allElements as $val){
            if(in_array('ele_4af42ceac7810',$toRemValArray)){
                $value = $form->getElement($val->getName());
                $value->removeValidator('ele_4af42ceac7810');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know whether my code is having any issue

Thanks 
Mohammad Tareque

Answer (score 4):

You should remove the validator **BEFORE** calling **$form->isValid()**.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I came up with was overriding the `isValid` method on my form class and removing the validator on the password field if it was left blank:

```
public function isValid($data)
{
    if (empty($data['password'])) {
        $this->form
             ->getElement('password')
             ->clearValidators();

        $this->form
             ->getElement('password_confirm')
             ->clearValidators();
    }
    return $this->form->isValid($data);
}
```

The `$this->form` is referred to the form being extended by composition, the solution works when extending a Zend Form descendent class as well.

Just a side note, this solution *won't work if* the password field is **required**

Answer (score 1):

Your code is removing a validator by name

```
$value->removeValidator('ele_4af42ceac7810');
```

This is typically something like `NotEmpty` or `Regex` as opposed to the element name.

Maybe you want

```
$value->clearValidators();
```

Also, +1 Ismael - you should remove it prior to calling `$form->isValid()`